# How do I print something multiple times with one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I would like this iframe to print multiple times when someone clicks print. This is what I have so far, but it is only printing once. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
$("#printing").on('click',function(){
                var printYesNo = 1;     
                alert("hi");    
                for(var count = 1; count < 3; count++) {
                    $('body').append('<iframe src="flyer.php?userNow='+count+'" id="printIFrame" name="printIFrame"></iframe>');
                    $('#printIFrame').bind('load', 
                        function() {                                
                            window.frames['printIFrame'].focus(); 
                            window.frames['printIFrame'].print();                           
                        }                       
                    );
                }
});
```

Comment: You're adding multiple IDs with same value, so the HTML will be invalid and jQuery won't recognize the list of elements, but only the first matched(so the first iframe).

Comment: @LightStyle, you mean change it from id="printIFrame" to class=?

Comment: Yes, it's a solution. Otherwise you can use `iframe[name='printIFrame']` as jQuery selector to select all the iframes. But a class is surely a better choice.

Comment: Either use a class or add a number to your id. If you use a class then you don't need to bind that onload function in the for loop.

Comment: Just a side note, in your case it would be better to use `$(document).on('load', '.printIFrame', function() {...});` because they're dynamically added elements.

Comment: @LightStyle, Thanks! That's partially working now. It's going through the print dialog multiple times. However, the count is never being updated in the url (the count is displayed on the page to be printed...it's shown in the code I wrote).

Comment: Are you trying to open multiple print dialogs at the same time, or print the iFrames once in the same print dialog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving each element the same ID and name, and then focusing printing etc. It just seems wrong, and doing it a little differently will trigger multiple print dialogs in some browsers (printing an iFrame is not cross browser) :

```
$("#printing").on('click', function () {
    for (var count = 1; count < 13; count++) {
        (function(k) {
            $('<iframe />', {
                id   : 'printIFrame' + k,
                name : 'printIFrame' + k,
                on   : {
                    load: function() {
                        this.contentWindow.focus();
                        this.contentWindow.print();
                    }
                },
                src  : 'flyer.php?userNow=' + k,
            }).appendTo('body');
        })(count);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJUBe/1/)

Comment: This actually mostly works. The only problem is when I increase the count, the only pages to print are the ones with the 1st number and the last number. Any ideas?

Comment: that didn't seem to change anything

Comment: So I take that back. The loop is seemingly working properly in firefox, but in chrome, it just prints the 1st and last id.

Comment: @gotguts - seems strange, I'm using Chrome, and all the print dialogs open, and the value of k seems correct ?

Comment: I take it you have this function within an onload function and then there is a very basic body, correct? I can't figure out for the life of me why I am getting a different result than you.

Comment: As an aside, this isn't working for another chrome user as well.